# how to send parament and redirect with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My framework is codeigniter .

I would like to do this :
when the user is not login and click on a `url` that does not have enough permission to see it and I want to redirect user by current `url` to `login` page and after `login`, I redirect user to previous `url` .

for example :

```
//user is not login and click on below `url`. I want to keep `profile` address
//and redirect to `enter` page with `profile` address.
www.example.com/profile

//after login, user will redirect to previous url (www.example.com/profile).
```

my code :

```
function userNotLogin(){

        $cu = current_url();
        $cu = urlencode($cu);
        redirect(base_url().'index/enter/'.$cu);
}
```

//login page

```
function enter($before_url)
    {
        if($this->isLogged())
        {

            if($before_url)
            {
                var_dump($before_url);
                return;

            }else{
                redirect(base_url());
            }

        }else{
            $data = array();
            $this->view('page_register_login' , $data );
        }

    }
```

but `var_dump($before_url);` returns `string(5) "http:"`    .

Comment: Instead store `current_url()` you may store `controller/method` in session and then use `redirect($before_url)`

Comment: for login view your are using new page or using bootstrap modal ?

Answer (score 0):

for that you will need to use **user_agent** library of CodeIgniter.

Like that --

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

It will work 100%, please use this...

Exmaple --

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $arr = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => md5($password),
            'user_type' => 'admin'
            );
        $result = $this->common_model->getMultiple('panel_login',$arr);
        if(!empty($result )){
            $this->session->set_userdata('unique_id',$result[0]['s_no']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$result[0]['username']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('password',$result[0]['password']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('type',$result[0]['user_type']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('status',$result[0]['status']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_activity',time());
            redirect($this->agent->referrer()); 
        }else{
            redirect('login_view');
        }

    }
```